# Disable function if script is hosted elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the js script with custom jQuery function and I want to make it so it works only if it's loaded from one host, is there any way to make it work with some kind of conditional stuff like

```
if (hostname == example.com) {
   function content
} else {
  alert "I don't work";
}
```

Comment: It's loaded in a php file... but it's standalone JS file with function

Comment: In javascript there is option to get location it is `location.hostname`

Comment: I've just edited your question but now I'm thinking... do you want the condition to be in the PHP file so that the JS file is not loaded at all or do you want the condition in the JS file itself. It's hard to tell from your pseudocode.

Comment: In the JS itself, so if someone downloads it and uploads to their server it does not work....

Comment: That will never stop anyone that really wants your script. Too easy to change your script to remove such checks (even when minified/obfuscated).

Comment: Agreed, you can't prevent client-side script theft.

Comment: @DinoL. Impossible, the license of the script is the only thing you can set, technically you cannot prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

If your jQuery function interacts with the server, then yes, you can check on the server-side if a user is authenticated, a certain session variable is set, etc. But that only applies to things you are doing on the server.

If your function does not interact with the server, then no, it could be loaded from anywhere, run and modified by anybody, etc.

Comment: Note: you need to take into caching of the script file too. Either block the entire page, or you need to ensure the script request is not cached.